# Can not put a animated background on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: sudo

I go to the terminal: (Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal), and typed the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ilap/lwp` and I pressed the enter key, and in the Terminal window it said: `Joe is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported`.

Comment: Are you the System Administrator?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the `sudo` command, you will have to enter your user's password when it is asked. You can't simply press the enter key to ignore it.